# Attribute that is not null when an other attribute is also not null in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, create-table, notnull

I wanted to create a table for Articles, that can have (but don't need to have) a link to an img-Source. For all Articles that have the link also an img-Type is needed (which should be 'png', 'svg' or 'jpg'). I don't quite understand how I can make the img-Type field not null only for values where the img-Src field is not null.

Here is my code (without not null/null constraints for the fields img-Type and img-Src)

```
create TABLE Article(
articleID varchar(15) primary key ,
articleDescription varchar (80) null ,
imgSrc varchar (20)  ,
imgType  char(3),
check imgType = 'png' or imgType = 'svg' or imgType = 'jpg'
);
```

Comment: What's the question? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `check (imgType IN ( 'png', 'svg', 'jpg'))`

Comment: I'm using postgresql and the question is how I can make the imgType attribute not null, but only if imgSrc is also not null. So i don't need to have an imgSrc value but if I have one I also need a value for imgType.

Comment: @DerWolferl `check imgSrc is null or imgType is not null`. That way the constraint passes if imgSrc is null, and checks that imgType is not null if imgSrc is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a new constraint where you check if both values are null or both values are not null

```
check (imgSrc is not null and imgType is not null 
    or imgSrc is null and imgType is null)
```

Comment: This forces imgType to be null if imgSrc is null, which is not necessary according to the original. If this additional constraint is irrelevant or undesirable then you can just check if `imgSrc is null or imgType is not null`. This way you don't even check the value of `imgType` if `imgSrc` is null.